# What limit does the following inequality involving the sum of divisors and Euler totient functions reach?

Tags: number-theory, limits, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Consider the following inequality:

$$\frac{6}{{\pi}^2} < \frac{\sigma(n)\phi(n)}{n^2} \lt 1.$$

For the even perfect numbers, this inequality seems to converge to 1. Here's the following ($5$ decimal) values for the first $5$ perfect numbers:

$$0.66666,0.85714,0.96774,0.99212,0.99987$$

**Question:** Does the convergence to $1$, if it can be proven, show that there are an infinite number of even perfect numbers?

Comment: an equality does not "converge". Not sure whether the expression converges, I would rather think it oscillates. Moreover, are the perfect numbers the only ones giving a value near $1$ ?

Comment: By convergence to $1$, I meant $0.99999999999999999...$. I cannot respond to your questions since it involves numerical calculations I am not equipped to do. For perfect numbers (the only ones considered here) and on the basis of just 5 values, it doesn't seem to oscillate.

Comment: @Peter, you are welcome to edit and correct the post.

Comment: The perfect numbers are not the only ones giving a value near $1$. In fact the primes (which there are infinite) give values much closer to $1$ (and we can say they converge to $1$.)

Comment: @player3236, can we use the result you mention to show there are a finite or an infinite number of perfect numbers?

Comment: Not by a long shot.

Comment: We have good reasons to assume that infinite many even perfect numbers exist and no odd, although both claims are still unproven. But such simple sequences won't answer such deep questions.

Comment: @user25406:  When you refer to *perfect numbers* in the OP, please take note that there are two kinds:  *odd* and *even*.  To avoid confusion, please specify explicitly that you are only considering *even perfect numbers*.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris, I added that only even perfect numbers are considered. It was clear because no one has ever found a single odd perfect number so talking about a limit of numbers whose existence has not been confirmed is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the even perfect numbers. (We don't know if odd ones exist)

By [Euclid-Euler Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem), $n = 2^{p-1} (2^p - 1)$ for some prime $p$ and $2^p-1$.

$$\phi(n)=\phi(2^{p-1})\phi(2^p-1) = 2^{p-2}(2^p-2)$$

$$\frac {\sigma (n) \phi(n)}{n^2} = \frac {(2n)(2^{p-2}(2^p-2))}{n (2^{p-1} (2^p - 1))} = 1-\frac 1{2^p-1}$$

hence this value does converge to $1$ (for the even perfect numbers).

However, as the existence of an infinite number of perfect numbers (or Mersenne primes) is not proven yet, I would presume this argument leads nowhere.

Comment: It is conjectured that infinite many Mersenne primes exist, but a proof is out of reach apparently. But I do not think that the convergence of this sequence would be shown then, we only would have a convergent partial sequence.

Comment: Here I naïvely used "convergence" to denote this property of the sequence $1-\frac1{2^p-1}$. If it is finite we cannot use "convergence", indeed.

Comment: @Peter, no I only considered the perfect numbers, not all the positive integers. It's clearly stated in the post.

Answer (score -1):

(Note:  This is too long for a comment and complements [player3236](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/435724)'s answer.)

Consider a hypothetical odd perfect number $N$.

From the following source:
[Advanced Problem H-661, On Odd Perfect Numbers, Proposed by J. L´opez Gonz´alez, Madrid, Spain and F. Luca, Mexico (Vol. 45, No. 4, November 2007), Fibonacci Quarterly](https://www.fq.math.ca/Problems/Advanced_Problems_NOV2009.pdf), we have the bounds
$$\dfrac{240}{217\zeta(3)} < \dfrac{\sigma(N)\varphi(N)}{N^2} < 1,$$
where we have the rational approximation
$$\dfrac{240}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.92008188672520641697672952496390495972393334311564395865.$$

Note that we also have
$$\dfrac{6}{{\pi}^2} \approx 0.607927101854026628663276779258365833426152648.$$

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to Player3236's answer and more importantly doesn't answer the question. The previous answer proved that the limit is $1$, this answer did not prove anything. I suppose one has to prove first that there are odd perfect numbers before one can prove the expression converges to a given limit.

Comment: @user25406:  Well, if you insist, Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number $N$ must have the form $N = q^k m^2$, where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,m)=1$.  Your expression then takes the form
$$\bigg(\frac{\sigma(N)}{N}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{\varphi(N)}{N}\bigg) = 2\cdot\bigg(\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{\varphi(m)}{m}\bigg),$$
which can be rewritten as
$$2\cdot\bigg(\frac{q-1}{q}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{\varphi(m)}{m}\bigg),$$
*but that is the best that we could do*. $\ldots$ (continued)

Comment: Similarly, much like you say that "one has to prove first that there are odd perfect numbers before one can prove the expression converges to a given limit", I can also say that *one has to prove first that there are infinitely many even perfect numbers before one can prove that the expression converges to $1$, otherwise you only have
$$1 - \frac{1}{2^p - 1}$$
which does get close to, but never actually reaches $1$*."

Comment: Answer to your first comment: I never insisted for another comment from you. My post was not about odd perfect numbers so your answer and your comment bring nothing to the discussion. It's your right to keep posting on odd perfect numbers but it's not to change the topic of discussion on my post.

Comment: Answer to your second comment. If you have anything to say about the answer of Player3236, you should make a comment below his answer not below yours so he can answer you.